# how make "magit log" show entire log message

Tags: magit

I have a commit with a message like this:

```
Contact Inquiries

todo: current user detection
import old table
actionmailer + mailgun
```

Magit log only shows "Contact Inquiries", and not the other 4 lines.
How can I make magit show me full message in the log.

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>RET</kbd> to view the commit at point in another buffer.

You can also view the full commit message and some other information directly in the log by enabling the respective (pseudo) argument in the log popup using <kbd>- h</kbd>. But that isn't supported very well and looks strange when also using `--graph`.

Comment: Just to add to this, you edit the logging popup using Shift-L when in the magit-log buffer, you can then add headers using -h, then g to update the buffer